# Count the number of characters from the string and int inputted by a user in python

Tags: python

Hi I wanted to count the characters in the string or int inputted by a user, and store the counted value and use it in a operation.

ex. the counted characters is 5 and I would subtract it to 10

Comment: assign user input to a var called `x`, then use `len(x)`

Comment: example ; x = input("name:")
       y=len(x)
would this work?

Comment: @Yuta Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

An example is

```py
while True:
    name = input("what is your name?")
    print(len(name))
```

Or you can use `len(name)` function to count it without actually printing it at this point

Comment: I already tried the len function and it counts the characters but is it storable to a variable

Comment: b=50
name =  input(Name")
a = len(name)
c=a-b
d=" "
print (d*c + "*")
i tried this one but it doesnt read the value

Comment: thanks for the answers + sign dont work but the comma one should

Comment: New here too bruhh just tried my best to help lol but the Len count can be stored an int(I guess) or as a string